# Why is my code searching for an index that doesn't exist?

Tags: python, runtime-error, wordle-game

Before explanation, this will make a lot more sense if you've played the online game Wordle, as I am attempting to recreate it with an AI add-on in Python 3.

I have the player input a 5 letter strings that is split into a 5 item list, and a 5 letter string representing the word split into a 5 item list. These are then both duplicated as lists "guessCopy" and "wordCopy" with the lines.

```
guessCopy = guess[:]
wordCopy = word[:]
```

to make sure I don't irreversibly mess with the data of the word.

When checking for "yellow" letters in a guess, my program will replace characters that are the same in a word and in a guess with "0" or "1", with these bits of code here:

```
if guess[y] == word[y]:
    results[y] = "Green"
    word[y] = 1
    guess[y] = 0
```

and

```
if word.count(character_x) > 0:
    results[y] = "Yellow"
    word[word.index(guess[y])] = 1
    guess[y] = 0
```

After each run of the code to get the color results of each letter, I would add the results to a list "results" and then revert the word back to its original status. I do that so next time I run it, I don't get an error trying to search for a "0" or a "1" in the word that isn't there.

It's this line of code: word[word.index(guess[y])] = 1, that's causing me some problems.

This only causes me problems around 2 out of 5 times, but this code is run 6 times over the course of the program and it will almost always crash, every time. It gives me the error message:

> IndexError: list index out of range

and, on occasion:

> ValueError: 0 is not in list

I didn't recognize either error message, so, of course, I looked them up here. None of the answers seemed to apply to my problem, and the debug does practically nothing. It just seems to randomly break and I don't know why, but it happens too frequently to be ignored.

Comment: Help us help you - share a [mcve]

Comment: Just before that line, add some [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) statements: `print(y)`, `print(guess[y])`, `print(word.index(guess[y]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to implement something similar to [wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html), the issue arises from your approach to replacing characters in `word` and `guess` lists. You are altering the original lists when you set `word[y] = 1` and `guess[y] = 0` in the first code block. Consequently, in subsequent iterations, the condition `word.count(character_x) > 0` can fail because `1` and `0` are invalid characters in the original word (assuming like worldle the word only contain English alphabet letters )

The `IndexError: list index out of range` occurs because `word.index(guess[y])` is trying to find an index for a character that has been replaced with `0`, which might not exist in `word` anymore. Similarly, `ValueError: 0 is not in list` happens when `0` (set in previous iterations) is not found in `word`.

To resolve this, you should avoid altering the original lists `word` and `guess` directly. Instead, use a separate list to keep track of the positions matched (green) or found elsewhere in the word (yellow). Try something like this:

1. Initialize a new list, say `matched`, with the same length as `word` and `guess`, filled with `False`.
2. First, mark all green positions (exact matches) in `matched` as `True`.
3. Then, for yellow checks, only consider characters in `word` whose corresponding `matched` value is `False`.

```py
matched = [False] * len(word)  # Initialize matched list

# Check for green letters
for y in range(len(guess)):
    if guess[y] == word[y]:
        results[y] = "Green"
        matched[y] = True

# Check for yellow letters
for y in range(len(guess)):
    if not matched[y] and guess[y] in word:
        # Find the first unmatched occurrence in word
        for w in range(len(word)):
            if word[w] == guess[y] and not matched[w]:
                results[y] = "Yellow"
                matched[w] = True
                break
```

Comment: I've just updated the question, thank you for taking the time to answer. Before editing both the word and guess I make copies of them, so I don't think the "matched" list idea will do very much.